# Imported PNG images in Gimp aren't transparent

Tags: gimp, transparency, png, import

I opened a PNG image as a layer in Gimp, expecting the background to be transparent. Instead, the whole squared background is visible and covering the image under it. What exactly am I doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: A PNG can have transparency or not. Try some other viewer, including any browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You very likely imported a non-transparent PNG. How did you obtain the PNG? There are web image sites that deliver a non-transparent PNG unless you pay (or where the sample is non transparent, with transparency replaced by the checkerboard pattern)....

You can check the PNG in your browser(s) (`File>Open...` in Firefox, drag and drop in Firefox and Chrome). These browsers don't display transparency as a checkerboard so if there is a checkerboard it is part of the image.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know that. I guess I'll have to be more observant next time.